# Android: Error inflating class fragment (with custom pageradapter)

Tags: android

I seem to fail to load my fragments which are located in a Linear layout which is inflated via my custom adapterpager. Here is the left_middle.xml:

```
<fragment class="com.example.testtabswipe.LeftFragment"
    android:id="@+id/left_fragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    </fragment>

<fragment class="com.example.testtabswipe.MiddleFragment" <----- this is where it complains
    android:id="@+id/middle_fragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >       
</fragment>
```

```
11-15 15:43:12.104: E/AndroidRuntime(12509): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 15:43:12.104: E/AndroidRuntime(12509): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
...
11-15 15:43:12.104: E/AndroidRuntime(12509):    at com.example.testtabswipe.MainActivity$SectionsLargePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(MainActivity.java:295)
```

This is the line in my activity:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = null;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_middle, container, false); // this is line 295
            break;
        case 1:
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_rightright, container, false);
            break;
        }
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }
```

And here is my MiddleFragment:

```
public class MiddleFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "1";
    private GridView gridView;
    Button btn;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        MiddleFragment fragment = new MiddleFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.middle_fragment, container, false);

        Log.d("Karl", "This does not work");

        initilizeComponents(view);
        initilizeListeners(view);


        //gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        //gridView.setAdapter(new DepartureAdapter(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }

    private void initilizeComponents(View view) {

    }

    private void initilizeListeners(View view) {
        RelativeLayout middleFragmentLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.middle_fragment);
        middleFragmentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "you clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Any ideas?